# Ember js search nested routes

Tags: javascript, search, ember.js, nested-routes

I'm trying to make a search inside a nested route particularly that shares model.

Here's my code example

Products and Search returns a json

Router

```
Market.Router.map ->
    @resource 'products'
    @resource 'search', { path: "products/search" }
    @resource 'product', { path: "products/:product_id" }
```

The rest adapter api url I'm trying to achieve is the following:

http://api.url:3000/v1/products/search?search_terms="rope"

I have an action inside a header menu controller for the search

How do I find records inside a nested route?

```
Market.HeaderMenuController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    searchText: null,
    actions: {
        searchResults: function(){
             this.store.find('product', 'search?search_terms='+this.searchText);
             this.store.find('search', { "search_terms":this.searchText });
        }
    }
});
```

I get the following errors -

> Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an `id` for Market.Product in an object passed to `push`
>
> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an `id` for Market.Product in an object passed to `push`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is caused by the JSON being returned from your `this.store.find` method. Ember-data expects all model objects to have an `id` property specified. If you inspect the JSON that is returned from your API endpoint, you will probably find there is no `id` property on the object.

Make sure that the JSON you're returning has an `id` property defined (on each 'product' object) and the error should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This was my temporary approach, probably there are better solutions out there.

In order to achieve a nested resource for search, you can do the following.

The api endpoint was

http://api.url:3000/v1/products/search?search_terms="rope"

I create a custom adapter for search route

```
Market.SearchAdapter = Market.ApplicationAdapter.extend(
  namespace: "v1/products"
)
```

A custom pluralization for search, and avoid having "searches" endpoint

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.rules.uncountable['search'] = true;
inflector = Ember.Inflector.inflector;
inflector.irregular('search', 'searches');
```

Now you can run a store find for search

```
this.store.find('search', { 'search_terms': this.searchText });
```

With the previous endpoint.